# Unable to determine if a string is included in my Json key in angular2+

Tags: javascript, angular

My json key is like this -

"Virtual Account Number Verification IN.items.properties.Client Code.type" : "array"

I want to determine if "Client Code" is present in the above json key.

I tried doing it using -

```
var abc = "Virtual Account Number Verification IN.items.properties.Client Code.type"

var pqr =  "Client Code"

abc.includes("." +pqr+".")
```

But it doesn't work. 
What is the other workaround ?

Comment: `var yesItDoesWork = abc.includes("." +pqr+".");` - now ... what's the value of `yesItDoesWork` ... the code you wrote works, it's just that you discard the result

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"? [returns `true` here](https://jsbin.com/povevofodo/edit?js,console)

Comment: Your code snippet returns true, which means it is working as intended.

Comment: the code snippet returns nothing @AkashSrivastav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works as intended. The difference between them that `ES 5` has `indexof` method, however `includes` came in `ES 6`.

If `abc` is type of string, then you can use the following code snippet:

```
var abc = "Virtual Account Number Verification IN.items.properties.Client Code.type";
var pqr =  "Client Code";
var isContains = abc.indexOf(`.${pqr}.`);
if(isContains != -1)
    console.log(`There is a client code`)
else 
    console.log(`There is no a client code`)
```

Another way with `includes`:

```
var abc = "Virtual Account Number Verification IN.items.properties.Client Code.type";
var pqr =  "Client Code";

if(abc.includes(`.${pqr}.`))
    console.log(`There is a client code`)
else 
    console.log(`There is no a client code`)
```

Comment: `indexOf` is es5, es6 is 4+ years old and `.includes` was defined in ES6 - this code doesn't even surround the `pqr` with `.`'s therefore could potentially return false positives

Comment: @VLAZ The OP's code works as intended. The difference between them that ES5 has `indexof` method, however `includes` came in ES 6.

Comment: @downvoter please tell me what's reason to downvote? It would be really helpful to improve my reply. It is really important to me to improve answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why it is not working , have a look at here . Check your `console` it might be the case of something else .

```js
var abc = "Virtual Account Number Verification IN.items.properties.Client Code.type"

var pqr =  "Client Code"
console.log("." +pqr+".")
console.log(abc.includes("." +pqr+"."));
```

`true` if the search string is found anywhere within the given string; otherwise, `false` if not.[about includes and browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)